# Javascript - Numeric associative array alternatives

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, each object has an unique id and I want to link multiple (sometimes hundreds) extensions to an object linked by it's id.

Here a psuedo code example:

```
var objects = [
    {id:15,name:"client John Doe"},
    {id:28,name:"server"}
]

var extensions = [
    28:[
        {
            name:"watch errors",
            command: "tail -f error.log"
        },
        {
            name:"clear errors",
            command: "> error.log"
        }
    ]
]
```

This is not valid javascript, what is the best alternative to create an numeric associative array?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an object literal instead of an array:

```
var extensions = {
    28: […]
};
```

You can access it by `extensions[28]` (or `extensions["28"]`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you use object notation. I would also recommend enclosing the 28 in quotes. This will help avoid potential confusion of thinking it is an array index when it is not.

```
var objects = [
    {id:15,name:"client John Doe"},
    {id:28,name:"server"}
]

var extensions = {
    "28":[
        {
            name:"watch errors",
            command: "tail -f error.log"
        },
        {
            name:"clear errors",
            command: "> error.log"
        }
    ]
}
```

You could then read the property as `extensions["28"][0]`, you can't do `extensions.28[0]` however.

Comment: You mean: var extensions = { "28":[]}

Comment: Indeed, corrected it. That's what I get for not testing first. Also not 100% sure this is what the you want to do, but we'll see!

Comment: There is no need for quotes.

Comment: Quotes are a good practice when using non-standard identifiers. It helps distinguish from array indices or other possible points of confusion. I'd also recommend accessing it as extensions["28"] in most cases to again prevent issues. You are correct though, in the case of numbers it isn't strictly required.

Comment: *"Quotes are a good practice when using non-standard identifiers"* That's the first time I here about this good practice. Either way, your answer suggests that quotes are required, which is not the case (and the point of my comment).

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify. However, just because it's the first time you heard it, doesn't mean it's not true. There is a first time we each heard everything ;) I think anything that helps avoid confusion, like me looking at your code and seeing expressions[28] and thus assuming there is an expressions[27] is a good practice. Others read your code too, so if they read it and are confused, that's bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

**Use an Object**

```
var extensions = {
    28:[
        {
            name:"watch errors",
            command: "tail -f error.log"
        },
        {
            name:"clear errors",
            command: "> error.log"
        }
    ] };
console.log(extensions[28][0].name); // "watch errors"
```

Note that you can't use `extensions.28` to access this, you need to use `extensions[28]`.

**Use a Sparse Array**

The array you're looking for here is perfectly legal...you just can't specify it as a literal.

```
var extensions = [];
extensions[28] = [
            {
                name:"watch errors",
                command: "tail -f error.log"
            },
            {
                name:"clear errors",
                command: "> error.log"
            }
        ];

console.log(extensions[28][0].name); // "watch errors"
```

Now you have an array, with a value at index 28, and indices 0-27 undefined.

Now, it's worth noting as a caveat here that lots of people hate sparse arrays in javascript. Also, you'll need to be careful iterating through them, accessing length, etc. But they ARE a valid part of the language, and this is one use-case for them.